# Moment.js and moment timezone getting current time separated in seconds, minutes and hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have referenced two scripts into my project:

```
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

And now the code part:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var now = moment(); // current timestamp, using your machine's time zone

        var nowNY = now.tz('America/New_York'); // converted to NY time zone
        console.log("Current time in NYC: " + nowNY.format());
    });
</script>
```

In console this displays the following:

```
Current time in NYC: 2018-12-13T03:59:13-05:00
```

Now I just need to extract the part with the 03 (hours) 59 (minutes) and 13 (seconds)

But I'm not sure how to do this, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`format('HH:mm:ss')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

> This is the most robust display option. It takes a string of tokens and replaces them with their corresponding values.

You can use `HH` for 00-24 hours, `mm` for 0-59 minutes and `ss` for seconds.

Here a live sample:

```js
var now = moment(); // current timestamp, using your machine's time zone
var nowNY = now.tz('America/New_York'); // converted to NY time zone
console.log("Current time in NYC: " + nowNY.format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is excellent ! Ty so much... I'd just need now to separate the minutes, hours and seconds into separate variables, how could I do that ? :D

Comment: @User987 Are you looking for [`hour()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/), [`minute()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/) and [`second()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/second/) getters?

Comment: @VicenzoC yes yes that's it

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@VincenzoC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4131048/vincenzoc)'s answer (and as he correctly added in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758278/moment-js-and-moment-timezone-getting-current-time-separated-in-seconds-minutes/53758584#comment94368839_53758309)), the moment library has specific Getters for hours, minutes, seconds if you want to use. Like this ([as dictated in the moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/second/))

`var now = moment();
console.log(now.hours());`

Or if you want to stay with the `format` function you can use it like this

`now.format('HH');
now.format('mm');
now.format('ss');`